# Exception found.....org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer using custom object Serializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have written a spring-kafka package using spring boot to send messages to a Kafka topic with "Key" as String and "Arraylist" as Value. "Custom Object" is a class having attributes item id, item name, and item ordered count.

Kafka Producer log shown below.

```
2021-10-29 00:09:34.147  INFO 16496 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [172.26.77.192:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = true
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.util.kafkaProducer.KafkaArrayListSerializer

2021-10-29 00:09:34.180  INFO 16496 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
2021-10-29 00:09:34.180  INFO 16496 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2021-10-29 00:09:34.180  INFO 16496 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-10-29 00:09:34.181  INFO 16496 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2021-10-29 00:09:34.182  INFO 16496 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.producer for producer-1 unregistered
2021-10-29 00:09:34.182 DEBUG 16496 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Kafka producer has been closed
ProcessOrders: Exception found.....org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
```

I have written a custom serializer as shown below.

```
package io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.util.kafkaProducer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.models.UpdateItemCount;

public class KafkaArrayListSerializer<UpdateItemCount> implements Serializer<ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>>{
    
    private final Serializer<UpdateItemCount> arrayListSerializer;
    
    public KafkaArrayListSerializer(final Serializer<UpdateItemCount> paramArrayListSerializer) {
        System.out.println("KafkaArrayListSerializer: Inside constructor.......");
        this.arrayListSerializer = paramArrayListSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount> customerOrderData) {
        System.out.println("KafkaArrayListSerializer: Inside serialize.......");
        System.out.println("Topic name......."+topic);
        
        int dataSize = customerOrderData.size();
        System.out.println("dataSize......."+dataSize);
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        Iterator<UpdateItemCount> arrayListIter = customerOrderData.iterator();
        try {
            out.writeInt(dataSize);
            while (arrayListIter.hasNext()) {
                final byte[] customerOrderDataToBytes =  arrayListSerializer.serialize(topic, arrayListIter.next());
                out.writeInt(customerOrderDataToBytes.length);
                out.write(customerOrderDataToBytes);
            }
            out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to serialize ArrayList", e);
        }
        
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

The Serde class for "Arraylist" is shown below.

```
package io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.util.kafkaProducer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

public class ArrayListSerde<T> implements Serde<ArrayList<T>>{
    
    private final Serde<ArrayList<T>> arrayListSerdeObj;
    
    public ArrayListSerde(final Serde<T> SerdeObj) {
        this.arrayListSerdeObj = Serdes.serdeFrom(new KafkaArrayListSerializer<>(SerdeObj.serializer())
                                                 , new KafkaArrayListDeserializer<>(SerdeObj.deserializer()));
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<ArrayList<T>> serializer() {
        System.out.println("ArrayListSerde: Inside Serializer.......");
        return arrayListSerdeObj.serializer();
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<ArrayList<T>> deserializer() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
      public void close() {
        arrayListSerdeObj.serializer().close();
      }

}
```

The Kafka Producer service code is show below:-

```
package io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.util.kafkaProducer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaSendCallback;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

import io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.models.UpdateItemCount;


@Service
@ConfigurationProperties
public class KafkaProducerService {
    
    
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> kafkaTemplateObj;
    private String KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME = "ItemsOrdered";
    private ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>>> asyncCall;
    private ProducerListener<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> producerListener;
    
    public KafkaProducerService(KafkaTemplate<String,ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> kafkaTemplateParam) {
        this.kafkaTemplateObj = kafkaTemplateParam;     
    }
    
    public KafkaTemplate<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> producerListener(ProducerListener<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> producerListener) {
        kafkaTemplateObj.setProducerListener(producerListener);
        return kafkaTemplateObj;
    }
    
    public void sendMessage(Integer PartitionId, String key, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount> UpdateItemCountArr) {
        
            try {

                System.out.println("KafkaProducerService:sending message");
                
                final ProducerRecord<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>> record = new ProducerRecord<String, ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>>(KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME, PartitionId, key,UpdateItemCountArr);

                System.out.println("KafkaProducerService: sending async call...");
                
                ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,ArrayList<UpdateItemCount>>> future = kafkaTemplateObj.send(record);
                 
                kafkaTemplateObj.flush();
                
            } catch(KafkaProducerException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception...." + ex);
                System.out.println("Exception msg...." + ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Exception root cause..." + ex.getRootCause());
                System.out.println("Exception stack trace..." + ex.getStackTrace());
            }
     }
    
}
```

The kafka configuration is shown below

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers = 172.26.77.192:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer = io.springbootlearn.orders.customerorders.util.kafkaProducer.KafkaArrayListSerializer
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=debug
logging.level.org.apache.kafka.clients=debug
```

I have confirmed that my Kafka setup is working fine by writing another program which sends messages to a different Kafka topic with both "Key" and "Value" as String. The consumer is able to fetch the messages from this topic.

Could anyone please help?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Help with what? You haven't described a problem.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your response. Apologies, the issue is that the package is unable to construct the Kafka producer. Please refer to the Kafka producer log at the very top of my question.

Comment: You should use the json/Avro/Protobuf serializers to send an encoded list. There's no need to write your own. Especially, you shouldn't use Java specific object byte formats

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks. Sorry but I am not familiar with Avro/Protobuf serializers. Could you please share a few examples?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka can only create serializers with a no argument constructor. For more complex objects you have to construct them yourself and pass into the default producer factory via a constructor or setter.

Comment: Thanks Gary, after much deliberation on this I have decided to go with JSON Serdes. It's much easier and gets the job done. Thanks for replying and helping.